# How to dispose sleepy connection programatically?- mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

Am using `MySQL` as Back end for my website, while executing the website.. at some phase i got the error as `Too many connections`.

Am using a class file for handling `mysql` transactions. in that class file i have a sub for closing the connections which is as follows:

```
 Public Sub CloseConn()
       ConnDB.Close()
       ConnDB.Dispose()
 End Sub
```

After getting the error i will restart the mysql for continue the operations. in mysql administrator i can saw that all the connections state is `Sleep`. how can i kill the sleepy connections programmatically?

Comment: Are you using a connection pool and are the connections being returned properly to the pool?

Comment: co connection pool is using

Answer (score 1):

mysqld will timeout DB Connections based on two(2) server options:

```
interactive_timeout
 wait_timetout
```

Both are 28800 seconds (8 hours) by default.

You can set these options in /etc/my.cnf

If your connections are persistent (opened via mysql_pconnect) you could lower these numbers to something reasonable like 600 (10 min) or even 60 (1 min). Or, if your app works just fine, you can leave the default. This is up to you.

You must set these as follows in my.cnf (takes effect after mysql restart):

```
[mysqld]
 interactive_timeout=180
  wait_timeout=180
```

If you do not want to restart mysql, then run these two commands:

```
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout = 180;
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 180;
```

Comment: can i include it in my class? where i creating the connection?

Comment: write it to your my.cnf

Comment: can i set it programmatically? from my vb codings?

Comment: you can set it(SET Global and ...) from your front end